# calculate matrix east west diagonal in C#

Tags: c#

any body can help me for a program 
I want to make a code that can fill a matrix that way in C#

```
0 0 0 0 5
0 0 0 4 0
0 0 3 0 0
0 2 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
```

i am working on it for a week but i dident find a solution 
thank you

Comment: Here is solution for another week: *var result = Enumerable.Range(0,25).GroupBy(k=> k/5).Select(g=> g.Select(k=> (k % 5 == (5-1-k/5)) ? 5-k/5 : 0).ToArray()).ToArray();*

Comment: a solution for another year  .thank you but I did not understand

Answer (score 1):

Here is your solution. At least try to understand how it works.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var n = 5;
            var result = Enumerable.Range(0,n*n).GroupBy(k=> k/n).Select(g=> g.Select(k=> (k % n == (n-1-k/n)) ? k%n+1 : 0).ToArray()).ToArray();
            foreach(var r in result)
            {
                foreach(var a in r)
                {
                    Console.Write(" {0}", a);
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

thank you i found a solution

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApp5
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int[,] arr = new int[5, 5];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < 5; j++)
                {
                    if (i + j  == 4)
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = j + 1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        arr[i, j] = 0;
                    }
                    Console.Write(arr[i, j] + " ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's my attempt:

```
int[,] arr = new int[n,n];
for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < n; j++)
    {
        if(i+j-1 == n)
        {
            arr[i,j] = j+1;
        }
        else
        {
            arr[i,j] = 0;
        }
        Console.Write(arr[i,j] + " ");
    }
Console.WriteLine();
}
```

I haven't checked if this specific code works, but something like this should do the trick.